# how do i know the table is still the same and do something teradata/BTEQ

Tags: teradata

I'm trying to create a BTEQ script that hopefully automate tasks in Teradata SQL.

Problem: 
if I run a  select * from table A today in BTEQ

after two weeks I run the same query ( select * from table A )

if the table has not changed, how would I know that and tell BTEQ to exit the BTEQ scripts or Do something?

if the table has changed, how would I know that and RUN a Next sequence of/some additional scripts?

thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by *changed*? Modified data or modified table definition?

Comment: Hi dnoeth, i mean data in the table has been updated or some rows have been deleted.. not necessarily table structure but just the data within the table.

Comment: Even if the DBA switched on Object Use Count (which collects the number of Inserts/Updates/Deletes and a timestamp when that happened th last time) for that table you could miss modifications because it's cached and might be written with a few minutes delay. How big is that table and why do you need it?

Comment: not that huge but i found a .IF statement which can be used. I can use ACTIVITYCOUNT <condition> THEN <do something say .GOTO SOMELABEL>. however say that if my table is missing then what happens to my script is that it executes everything on the .LABEL

Comment: You can use ERRORCODE (or ERRORLEVEL) to branch to a different label or MAXERROR to quit the script.

Comment: `ACTIVITYCOUNT` references the count of latest statement (for example sel/ins/upd/del) before the `.if`. After a `select count(*) from table`the ACTIVITYCOUNT is 1, even if the table is empty, because the select delivered 1 row. To get the number of changed data in the table, you have to create a copy of the table and then later on you may check if those two tables differ `select top 1 * from ( select * from table minus sel * from table_backup)` and then `.if ACTIVITYCOUNT > 0 GOTO somelabel`. At somelabel you can then drop and create a new backup-table.

Comment: Why not use a trigger that would set a semaphore that the table data has been altered?